# Add ArrayList into Listbox Java

Tags: java, swing, jlist

So I'm trying to add an ArrayList to a Jlist, but I'm getting errors. Here is the code

```
private void BReActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
            NameList NL = new NameList();
            NL.name.add("a");
            NL.name.add("b");
            NL.name.add("c");
            NL.name.add("d");
            NL.name.add("e");
            for(int i=0; i < NL.name.size(); i++)
            {
                LOut.add(NL.name.get(i));
            }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors ?

Comment: No suitable method found for add(Object)

Comment: What are the types of `NL.name` and `LOut`? (I recommend not starting variable names with uppercase letters, btw).

Comment: NL.name is an ArrayList in a class named NameList and LOut is the JList

Comment: Just the raw types? So not `JList<String>` for example?

Comment: Nope, I use NetBean's design view fyi

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Answer (score 1):

```
LOut.add(NL.name.get(i));
```

1. First of all learn an use Java naming standards. Variable names do NOT start with an upper case character.
2. You don't "add" items directly to the JList. You add items to the `ListModel`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). The `ListDemo` code is a working example that shows how to add items to the `DefaultListModel`. The code also shows how to use proper variable names.

Comment: What is the difference of the Add method he mentioned in question, and the one you answered here ? Both looking same LOut.add(NL.name.get(i));

Comment: @MrunmayDeswandikar, I just highlighted the problem line in the code and gave two reasons that statement caused a problem. The proper solution is to add the items to the model as is demonstrated in the tutorial that I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the name field and try like below,

```
for(int i=0; i < NL.name.size(); i++)
{
   LOut.add(NL.get(i));
}
```

Comment: The ArrayList (called 'name') is in another class named NameList.java. So I had to Make an instance of NameList and then call the ArrayList